# input type="date", displaying week number

Tags: html, date, calendar

I have a date picker which is used to pick specific dates. In this datepicker, I would like to display the week number as a separate column - not necessarily as a selectable value, but just to get a look of in what week your date is situated.

```
<input type="week">
```

... doesn't quite cut it, since I need to be able to select a specific date, not just the week. In fact, I never need to select a week number, I just need to display it in the calendar.

Any tips on this?

Comment: I need to do the same did you have any luck with this?

Comment: The Blazor InputDate uses native html input type="date"
So the UI you see for selecting the date is built on Browser's way of displaying the control, MDN has some details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date
Creating such a control would not be impossible I think, at least Syncfusion solved this. But I don't seem to be able to inspect the DOM for the popup control ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution and it worked good for me, please if you see an error or you have a note, tell me to correct the solution!

```
//Code behind
private string WeekVal {get; set;}
private Dictionary<string,object> dic {get; set;} = new 
   Dictionary<string,object> {{"type","week"}};
protected override void OnInitialized()
 {
   var year= DataTime.Now.Year;
   var week= DataTime.Now.DayOfYear / 7;
   WeekVal= $"{year}-W{week}";
 }
 //Blazor page
 <inputText @attribute="dic" @bind-Value="WeekVal" />
```

`Safari and Firefox don't support it on desktop, and old versions of IE don't support it.` [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/week)